# how do I create a list from a sitemap.xml file to extract the url in python?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to create a code to extract a word from one scrape of images.
I'll explain, from a page sitemap.xml ,my code must try in every link present in this xml file,  found insiede each link if there a specific word, inside an image link.

the sitemap is adidas = http://www.adidas.it/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-IT-Library/it_IT/v/sitemap/product/adidas-IT-it-it-product.xml

this is the code i created for search the image contains the word "ZOOM" :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 html = requests.get(
'http://www.adidas.it/scarpe-superstar/C77124.html').text
 bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
 possible_links = bs.find_all('img')
 for link in possible_links:
  if link.has_attr('src'):
    if link.has_key('src'):
        if 'zoom' in link['src']:
            print link['src']
```

but im search a metod to scrape a list in automatic

thankyou so much

i try to do this for have list :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

 url = "http://www.adidas.it/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-IT-Library/it_IT/v/sitemap/product/adidas-IT-it-it-product.xml"

r = requests.get(url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for url in soup.findAll("loc"):
print url.text
```

but i cant to attach request..

i can find the word "Zoom" in any link present in sitemap.xml

thankyou so much

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: update the code in question instead of comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def make_soup(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    return soup
# put urls in a list
def get_xml_urls(soup):
    urls = [loc.string for loc in soup.find_all('loc')]
    return urls
# get the img urls
def get_src_contain_str(soup, string):
    srcs = [img['src']for img in soup.find_all('img', src=re.compile(string))]
    return srcs
if __name__ == '__main__':
    xml = 'http://www.adidas.it/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-IT-Library/it_IT/v/sitemap/product/adidas-IT-it-it-product.xml'
    soup = make_soup(xml)
    urls = get_xml_urls(soup)
    # loop through the urls
    for url in urls:
        url_soup = make_soup(url)
        srcs = get_src_contain_str(url_soup, 'zoom')
        print(srcs)
```

Comment: ok , but to find a word in a file xml ? 

in this http://www.adidas.it/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-adidas-IT-Library/it_IT/v/sitemap/product/adidas-IT-it-it-product.xml

i must search the word "Zoom" in any link present in file xml :) thankyou so much

Comment: print 0

because i search in each link present xml and print the img with word Zoom

in this update i search in xml in link address the word zoom.. but not inside each open link

Comment: its hard to explain :D sorry 

every link in sitemap contains a web page --- in each link, i must open and search the word "zoom"